# Как отправить Json с помощью библиотеки retrofit (android)

Tags: android, retrofit

Знаю, что при формировании запросов ретрофит и так превращает их в json, но возникла необходимость передать json такого вида

```
{
    "inv": [
        {
            "name": "value1",
            "pass": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если JSON надо отправить в теле запроса, то нужно создать поджо класс типа

```
class Login { String name = `` value1 ``; String pass=`` value2 ``;} and class Inv extends arraylist < Login >
```

В интерфейсе сервиса ретрофита в аргументах указать `@Body` типа  `Inv`.  `(getUserData(@Body Inv inv))`
В реквесте соответствено передать в параметрах созданный `new Inv` такой какой нужен. `(getServise().getUserData(inv))`